# Execute batch in case windows port is not used

Tags: windows, if-statement, batch-file

In a windows batch file, regularly executed by a chronjob, I would like to execute the following command:

```
netstat -ano|findstr 0.0:16250
```

in case it does return an empty string - meaning the port is not in use - I would like to execute `startA.bat`.

In case somthing like

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:16250   0.0.0.0:0        LISTENING       2452
```

is returned nothing should be done.

This should be done in an if-then-else statement

Could anyone write this 5 liner for me? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
netstat -ano|findstr "0.0:16250" >nul  || call startA.bat
```

If you want to transfer complete control to startA.bat then don't use the `call` keyword.